# How do I draw shapes in JOGL with OpenGL 4.0?

Tags: opengl, jogl

I'm trying to write code to draw shapes on my JOGL canvas. I have the canvas on screen, but I can't figure out how to draw shapes. In GL2 examples, I see examples like:

```
gl.glBegin( GL2.GL_LINES );
gl.glVertex3f( 0.0f,0.75f,0 );
gl.glVertex3f( -0.75f,0f,0 );
gl.glEnd();
```

However, this doesn't work for me when gl is an instance of GL4 (gl is an instance of GL2 in this example).

Comment: Hi Chris, you may wanna take a look to an [Hello Triangle](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/tree/master/jogl-samples/src/helloTriangle)

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL 3.x Core Profile has deprecated immediate mode statements.

Use vertex arrays or vertex buffers.

I cannot offer an example in JOGL, but in other languages, one of related calls is `glDrawArrays()`. You'll need to enable and set up the data source arrays before calling `glDrawArrays()`; if memory serves well, you'll be interested in `glEnableClientState()`, `glVertexPointer()` et al.